# MSR Partition causing Ubuntu instalation to be stucked?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

After i migrated windows 10 from my hdd to my ssd it worked fine.
But as i want to dualboot Ubuntu 14.04.03 i still have this task to do.
So i made a bootable usb stick for this Ubuntu version and wanted to install it. Therefore i created 3 partitions. 1 for the OS itself, 1 for the Home and 1 linux-swap partition. But gparted also shows me one partition, which filesystem can´t be detected. It´s 128 MB and i´m pretty sure it´s the MSR Partition for the ssd. So if i now want to install Ubuntu it stucks after i  need to check "Download Updates" and "Third-Party Software" and press Ok.
I´m pretty sure this happens because of the msr partition, but i don´t know what to do about it.
Please Help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The acronym "MSR" means "Microsoft Reserved." This partition is a standard part of recent Windows installations. It's basically unused space that Microsoft wants to be present so that its disk utilities will have some "scratch space" to be used for certain operations, if and when the need arises. This partition is almost certainly ***not*** the source of your problem. As it's present on the vast majority of new Windows installations, it's present on huge numbers of Ubuntu installations, so if it were causing problems, the Internet would be flooded with problem reports concerning the partition. That hasn't happened.

Offhand, my initial guess about your problem is that the installer is having trouble accessing an archive site because of a bad Internet connection -- either a temporary problem or something more systemic. If so, you might do better to disconnect your computer completely when doing the installation. You won't be able to download updates while installing, but you can do so after installing, when you'll be better able to experiment with different repository sites to find one that works for you.

That's just my initial guess, though. It could be that something completely different is causing your problems. If so, you may need to debug the problem further, as described here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingUbiquity